# How do I declare a variable with the variable name based on a string? Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have something like

```
year = 2017
```

How do I declare a new variable, like `sales_2017` except the suffix is based on the variable `year`?

For example, something like 
`sales_{year}.format(year=year)` except that would be the syntax for a string, not a variable.

Comment: Not a good idea.  Use a dictionary.

Comment: Why? the variable name isn't very useful, were you looking for a dictionary?